# Use a variable for the name in Hi {name} and get first name in it?`

Tags: java, outlook, ms-office

I have to send a mail to around 100 of users in my office and I am using Microsoft Outlook.

I have to keep them all in BCC.

And my mail format is :

```
Hi {name}

/////
////


Regards 
Thinker
```

So what I want is {name} should be replaced by First name of every person in BCC.

Is it possible?
thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2008/09/22/mail-merge-how-to-send-a-personalized-e-mail-to-many-people-at-once.aspx

It's amazing how many people don't "google" their question before planting it here...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to use a mail merge.

Check out this link for a how-to:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-send-personalized-e-mail-messages-to-your-e-mail-address-list-HA101990822.aspx?CTT=1

I am no expert on the subject, but this looks pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that because `{name}` is a variable of the program and can't be modificated